# nodejs find user in azure active directory

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory

i've a nodejs API.I need to develop a fucntionnality that based on a key search a user in azure active directory.

Someone can help me or indicate me some tutos about that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Preface

It'll depend a bit on if you want this to be entirely service-side without user interaction or if you want to run this in the context of the user.

This answer assumes the latter. The primary benefit of this approach is it will run the search based off the user permissions required (which may be less than enabling your app to do this as a service e.g. may not require admin consent). In general, all docs can be found at [Azure AD Developer Docs](https://aka.ms/aaddev).

#### Steps / Apps you need to build

You'll want to do the following things:

1. Sign in the end user to your client app (e.g. here's a [SPA sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2)).
2. Have this client app request tokens to your Node Web API (e.g. here's a [Node Web API that accepts tokens](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2).
3. Then you'll want to check out the [On-behalf-of protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). This will allow you to exchange this token for a token for the Microsoft Graph API.
4. You can then use the token for Graph to call the necessary `Users` endpoint [API endpoint for users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/azuread-users-concept-overview).

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact solution is not based on the user permission. The user has to select user existing in he azure AD. After the application will do some treatment for user selected. Like you have in sharepoint the possibility to select user to give access to a document library for example. I think that the search on the AD will be better on server side. But i don't find how i can implement that in nodeJs

Comment: @Mattious, what you've described sounds like the solution I have outlined above. You'll be executing the requests in the context of a user, but doing so from a node service (using the `On-behalf-of Auth flow`).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I understand your explanation but i don't find how to search a users. I find to get all users but not a search. Sorry if i miss something

Comment: No problem! To search, you'll use the same endpoint, but with a [Search](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter) parameter.

Comment: @Mattious can you share how you are fetching user?